# How to cancel a JavaScript from your site with another one?

Tags: javascript, web-hosting

I am making a site at 000webhost.com, but the problem is that they add a script at the bottom of every page to show ads, and even if I deleted it manually, it comes back.
It is placed at the very bottom of the page, even under the <*/html> tag (* is not included).
Is there a way to cancel it's function with another JavaScript or something? Here is the code that is placed:

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Comment: where is the code that is placed..?

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure that having to display those ads is a part of their terms of service. That's the price you have to pay for the "free" hosting. If you manage to somehow disable the ads they're likely to close your site down if they see it.

Comment: @Franky sorry this is my first question here and I was facing troubles adding the code. I did it if you can check it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you should not remove the adds(as its against the policy and probably will take down your site),
 you can do a simple trick if you want to hide the adds, Trick is  based on anchors, which are used as adds by `000.webhost`

change all your anchor tags to add a class: for example

```
<a class='myAnchor' />
```

this class will not be applied to any add than `000.webhost` provides.

add a css to your page

```
a:not(.myAnchor){
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Well I know nothing about Css so if you can explain more I will really appreciate it

Comment: @CyberShadow you can add a class to your anchors, so you can differentiate your anchors in the page with the webhost script injected anchors, now that you have differentiated them, you can hide all the anchors that are not your anchors.

Comment: Well sorry I think you will just ignore me but I am new to this.

Comment: So what is an "anchor"?

Comment: <a> tag is called an anchor.. thats something you should research now.. some [html and css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Comment: Oh you mean the links?

Comment: yes links means anchor.. adds displayed by webhost are actually anchors, they can also be inputs inside form, you shall also write `form:not(.myForm){
display:none;
}` in the same way, and add myForm class to all your forms

Answer (score 0):

You can set timer to constantly check for injected scripts and remove them, or you can hide ads with CSS rules or you can just leave it there and don't break their policy. There are plenty of hostings without any ads.

Comment: Can you dive an example please?

Answer (score 0):

you are on free hosting server and they are injecting adds script into your page please provide injected code here, i mean whatever html code injected by this script.other wise you need full access to server to know which service or things inject script into your page and stop them....